# Add arrow to middle of Visio connector?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

Is this possible?

I have a complex diagram and in order to help follow the paths I would like to have an arrow in the middle of the connector as well as the end to indicate direction. If I can have multiple arrows along the path that would be great as well.

I'm using Visio 2010 now but if there is a solution for any version I am open to it.

Thanks,

Clint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this at VisGuy.com and they gave me the answer.

http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=1893.0

The answer is line patterns. Setup a line pattern then use that pattern for your connector.

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to click on the line to open a label box and insert a symbol from Wingding3.  This can be moved to anywhere on the line, formatted in any way a font can and layered using 'bring forward' etc.